# Network discovery in .NET

Tags: c#, networking, device-discovery

I need to get a list of machine connected to the current computer, just like explorer do. I want to use their name to retrieve their shared path using NetShareEnum.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx)

Comment: You might also want to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385478(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accept the answer from [Shymep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624741/shymep).

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx

Thank you