# How to find out the list of devices on the local network

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, network-programming, signalr

I run the client and want to connect to the server on the same local network. For this, I enter the local server address and connect. Is it possible to find out the IP addresses of all devices on this network (to select the required ip by clicking on it, rather than typing in from the keyboard)?

How to implement a list with these IP addresses on C#?

Comment: This post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003012/network-discovery-in-net  points to a article which shows how to browser the network, which might help you.

Comment: I tried the suggestions there option, but it did not help me. If I use them then the program does not see any other computers and even mine.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come into my mind:
- Network discovery, as mentioned in the comments of your question
- Ping all IP addresses in your IP subnet (at least for IP4, I do not know about IP6) (or additionally also in the IP subnets that you want to search) and connect to those hosts that respond with an answer.

Both ways have advantages and disadvantages. The first will only find devices that are recognized by Windows. The second will only look in the IP ranges that you provide - you have to know them upfront. And the second way can take a long time if the network belongs to a subnet that has a lot of IP addresses (or you have to scan a lot of subnets).